# Expected running time in randomized algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

> In most of the calculation analysis of running times, we have assumed
>   that all inputs are equally likely. This is not true, because nearly
>   sorted input,  for instance, occurs much more often than is
>   statistically expected, and this causes problems, particularly for
>   quicksort and binary search trees.
>
> By using a randomized algorithm, the particular input is no longer
>   important. The random numbers are important, and we can get an
>   expected running time,  where we now average over all possible random
>   numbers instead of over all possible inputs. Using quicksort with a
>   random pivot gives  an O(n log n)-expected-time algorithm. This means
>   that for any input, including already-sorted input, the running time
>   is expected to be O(n log n),  based on the statistics of random
>   numbers. An expected running time bound is somewhat stronger than an
>   average-case bound but, of course,  is weaker than the corresponding
>   worst-case bound.
>
> First, we will see a novel scheme for supporting the binary search
>   tree operations in O(log n) expected time. Once again, this means that
>   there are  no bad inputs, just bad random numbers. From a theoretical
>   point of view, this is not terribly exciting, since balanced search
>   trees achieve this  bound in the worst case. Nevertheless, the use of
>   randomization leads to relatively simple algorithms for searching,
>   inserting, and especially deleting.

My question on above text is

1. What does author mean by "An expected running time bound is somewhat stronger than an average-case bound but, of course, is weaker than the corresponding  worst-case bound" ? in above text.
2. Regrading binary search trees what does author meant by "since balanced search trees achieve this  bound in the worst case"? my understanding for binary search trees worst case is  O(d), where d is depth of the node this can be "N" i.e., O(N). what does author mean by this is same as worst case above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Like the author explained in the sentence before: An expected time must hold for any input. Average case is averaged over all inputs, that is, you get a reasonably mediocre input. Expected time means no matter how bad the input is, the algorithm must be able to compute it within the bound if the random number god is nice (i.e. gives you your expected value, and not the worst possible thing like she often does).
2. **Balanced** binary search trees. They can't reach depth N because they are *balanced*.

Comment: The RNG is a female? I didn't know that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Author means that on average Quick Sort will produce slower results then O(n log n) (This is not correct for all sorting algorithms, e.g. for merge sort expected time == average time ==O(n log n)  and no randomization is needed)
2. O(d) = O(log n) for balanced trees

PS who is the author?

Comment: above text is from Data structures and Algorithm analysis by Mark Wessis.

Answer (score 0):

In randomized quicksort,even intentionally, we cant produce a bad input(which may cause worst case)since the random permutation makes the input order irrelevant. The randomized algorithm performs badly only if the random-number generator produces an unlucky permutation to be sorted.Nearly all permutations cause quicksort to perform closer to the average case, there are very few permutations that cause near-worst-case behavior and therefore probability of worst case input is very low...so it almost performs in O(nlogn).